# SQLAlchemy create engine and pyodbc DSN error

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, cloudera, pyodbc

I have a pyodbc connection via DSN, which works fine when I run pandas read_sql:

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='address', autocommit=True)
sql = "select * from users limit 100"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
```

But when I try to use pandas to_sql, using a sqlalchemy.create engine I receive the below error:

```py
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://username@address')    
df.to_sql('table_name', engine,if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Cloudera][ODBC] (11470) Transactions are not supported. (11470)
(SQLSetConnectAttr(SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT))') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)
```

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: Possibly somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664537/python-connection-to-hive

Comment: I saw this post. However, my first pyodbc.connect step works but my second attempt with sqlachemy gives an error.